# Always show absolute path in File Explorer address bar

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, address-bar

When using one of the Quick Access links in Windows 10 File Explorer, the address bar displays the following:

`ThisPC > Documents`

This is really annoying for navigating around as I often need to get to another folder near Documents, but I can't click the parent folder in the address bar because its not there and if I click the up or back button on the address bar it just takes me back to This PC.

As a developer this is just epically annoying.  I have to navigate quickly around the file system all the time.  Is there a way to just always have the address bar work off of the absolute path like old windows did?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most reliable method to do what you want is to pin your preferred folders to the **Quick Access** area after you have navigated to them via a [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention).

For example, the workgroup laptop on my home network is called `DELL-INSPIRON15`, so I can enter the following path in the address bar:

```
\\DELL-INSPIRON15\Users\Run5k\Documents
```

However, if your machine is on an Active Directory domain you will need to add **c$** to the syntax in order to map your local Documents folder via a UNC path:

```
\\DELL-XPS-9100\c$\Users\Run5k\Documents
```

After that, right-click **Quick Access** on the top-left and choose **Pin current folder to Quick access**.

Do the same for each folder within the **Quick Access** area, and you should see exactly the behavior that you want when you click on the up-arrow.

Comment: So for any ordinary desktop computer not connected to a network it is `\\Full_computer_name\c$\Users\User_name\Documents` . Your full computer name you can find here: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/do-you-need-help-locating-your-computer-name-00384381-8aa9-4398-b81b-475f09fed618

Comment: What is an `Active Directory domain`?

Comment: This solution does work BUT all paths then reference the network location. So if you open files from such a folder, all programs think that they're opening network locations.

Comment: In Windows 11, this works with Documents, but does not work with Videos, Music, Downloads, etc.

Comment: @Edward thanks for the update!

Answer (score 4):

For an alternative that is "less intrusive", i.e. doesn't involve editing `FolderDescriptions` or affect the shell namespace, see the alternative answer I recently added to this question: https://superuser.com/a/1768074/881098 . It adds an item to the background context menu of file folders that will navigate to the file system location for folders displaying namespace paths in the Address Bar such as:

- `<Full User Name>`  (shell:UsersFilesFolder)
- `This PC\Documents`

to (aasuming defaults for example only):

- `This PC\Windows (C:)\Users\<UserProfileFolder>`
- `This PC\Windows (C:)\Users\<UserProfileFolder>\Documents`

---

...and now back to the original answer...

---

Not sure if this will have unintended side-effects, but experimenting with the **Pictures** folder, I deleted the current **Quick Access** pin, then in the registry, deleted the **'ParsingName'** value under:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{0ddd015d-b06c-45d5-8c4c-f59713854639}
```

and

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB}
```

Restarted, navigated to `C:\Users\Keith` and pinned **Pictures** to **Quick Access**. the result was the Address Bar now showed **Pictures** path as a subfolder of the UserProfile folder rooted in the Desktop:

[image: Explorer Screenshot 1]

So then I delected the **ParsingName** under `{f3ce0f7c-4901-4acc-8648-d5d44b04ef8f}` (UsersFilesFolder) and that produced the desired result (after restarting Explorer):

[image: Explorer Screenshot 2]

Back up `HKLM\...\FolderDescriptions` before testing.

Comment: What's the key folderdescriptions id for the userprofile/homepath? e.g. `C:\Users\Keith`. Whenever I add my user folder to Quick Access it also gets a parsing name.

Comment: Do you mean the folder that displays with your long username in the Address bar? That's the `USersFilesFolder`. Its GUID is `{f3ce0f7c-4901-4acc-8648-d5d44b04ef8f}`.  The `ParsingName` value is `::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}`.

Answer (score 2):

The following is valid for Windows 10, I haven't upgraded to 11, so no clue as to how **Explorer** behavior may have changed.

---

Though this doesn't force **Explorer** to always display the file sytem path, it creates a context menu item that allows quick navigation to the file system location.

[image]

After execution:
[image]

This **PowerShell** snippet will navigate *all* open **Explorer** windows that are currently displaying a namespace junction to their file-system locaiton:

```
@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach({
    Try{$_.Navigate2($_.LocationURL)}
    Catch{}
})
```

To create a context menu shortcut to run this code without window flash:

```
$PSCommand      = '@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach({Try{$_.Navigate2($_.LocationURL)}Catch{}})'

$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($PSCommand))

$CommandLine    = 'cmd.exe /c start /min Powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand ' + encodedCommand

$Key            = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\Shell\NavToFSLocation'

[PSCustomObject]@{
    '(Default)' = 'Open file-system location'
    'Position'  = 'Top'
} | Set-ItemProperty -Path (mkdir $Key -Force).PSPath

New-Item -Path $Key -Name 'Command' -Value $CommandLine
```

If you prefer a `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\Shell\NavToFSLocation]
@="Open file-system location"
"Position"="Top"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\Shell\NavToFSLocation\Command]
@="cmd.exe /c start /min Powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand QAAoACgATgBlAHcALQBPAGIAagBlAGMAdAAgAC0AYwBvAG0AIABzAGgAZQBsAGwALgBhAHAAcABsAGkAYwBhAHQAaQBvAG4AKQAuAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAKAApACkALgBGAG8AcgBFAGEAYwBoACgAewBUAHIAeQB7ACQAXwAuAE4AYQB2AGkAZwBhAHQAZQAyACgAJABfAC4ATABvAGMAYQB0AGkAbwBuAFUAUgBMACkAfQBDAGEAdABjAGgAewB9AH0AKQA="
```

Comment: `To create a context menu shortcut to run this code without window flash:` What do I do with this code?

Comment: Figured it out: you run it in powershell with admin privileges. I've updated the answer to provide this info and fix a typo in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem. I don't use Quick Access. I use the Quick Launch toolbar and I wanted to have shortcuts in the Quick Launch toolbar that would open a window with the correct path in the Address Bar.

I solved the problem by creating shortcuts where the target is:

```
C:\Windows\explorer.exe <Full path of the desired target>
```

Such a shortcut opens a folder window where the path in the Address Bar is the actual path.

Answer (score 0):

Install Open-Shell https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu

If you don't want the start menu don't install that part.  Just select Classic Explorer in the installer. Then open it and click **Disable breadcrumbs**

Classic Explorer will add it's own annoying toolbar. Go to the View tab, Options, then uncheck **Classic Explorer Bar**

Answer (score -2):

Open Folderoption-Window (Explorer -> View -> Options -> Change Folder- and Search) and open the "View" tab. Under "Navigationarea" you will find an entry to show all folders. Activate it, that should do the trick.

[image]

Sorry, the wording might not be correct, I had to translate from my German version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already found this option and tried it.  It doesn't give me a quick shortcut to navigate around like quick access, it just shows me the current file tree.  I suppose if quick access can't used as I have used it in the past then as a last resort I could use this in concurrence with quick access, but it's less than ideal.